# Call jQuery function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code:

```
$(function(){ 
function someFunc(){
    /*do something*/
};
.............   
});
```

And now I want call someFunc from JavaScript like below:

```
function test(){    
$.fn.someFunc();
}
```

But it doesn't work! I've seen an article [how to call function in jquery from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533439/how-to-call-function-in-jquery-from-javascript). Is it possible?

Comment: `someFunc` is just a function defined inside another function... it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just defining a function within the closure (function) you pass into `$()` doesn't do anything to put it on the jQuery `fn` object. To do that, you have to do it explicitly:

```
$.fn.someFunc = someFunc;
```

Typically, you *wouldn't* do this within a callback on `$()`, you'd do it earlier. Plug-ins do this to add functionality, which should already be present *prior* to DOM ready.

By way of example, here's a silly little plug-in that turns text green:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.green = green;
  function green() {
    return this.css("color", "green");
  }
})(jQuery);
```

...which you might use from DOM ready:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".foo").green();

});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ivetir) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/ivetir/edit)

Note that the call to it is from a jQuery instance, not directly from `$.fn`.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You function `someFunc` is not a "jQuery function", it is a function defined inside a (jQuery) `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

You can't access it from outside because it is out of scope. Just declare it outside the load handler, and it will be accessible:

```
$(function(){ 
    // nothing here , but you can call someFunc() if you want
});

function someFunc(){
    /*do something*/
};

function test(){    
    someFunc(); // works!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery

```
$.fn.someFunc = myFunc;
function myFunc()
{
    // Code here
}
```

is similar to plain javascript's

```
function myObj()
{
    // Code here
}
var obj= new myObj();
obj.prototype.someFunc=myFunc;
function myFunc()
{
    // Code here
}
```

It's just a way to add a new property to an object (prototype inheritance) and jquery's fn is just an alias of javascript's prototype. To call my 'sumFunc' method that I have added earlier in to jquery object using

```
$.fn.someFunc = myFunc;
```

I can do

```
$('someElement').someFunc();
```

and this line will call taht function and do something to the 'someElement' (though I did nothing), hope it's clear enough. Look at T.J. Crowder's answer, it'll give you some more understanding.

Comment: *"... jquery's fn is just an alias of javascript's prototype..."* You mean `jQuery.prototype` (which is also, bizarrely, referenced from `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` because jQuery uses `new jQuery.fn.init` to create instances).

Comment: Yes, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755080/why-jquery-do-this-jquery-fn-init-prototype-jquery-fn, am I wrong with my understanding ?

Comment: `@Sheikh Heera`: I don't understand your question. All that link does is reiterate (incompletely) what I said above. Note that "javascript" != "jquery".

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder, I asked you whether I'm wrong or right at I said  "jquery's fn is just an alias of javascript's prototype", is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: `@Sheikh Heera`: "javascript's prototype" of *what*? The phrase doesn't make any sense to me just on its own. That's why I said "JavaScript != jQuery"